# Permanently deleted posts still exist

Tags: posts, theme-development, pages

So, I deleted multiple post of type page (sent them to trash, went to trash and permanently deleted them), but one of my functions didn't work like it was supposed to so I went and investigated, it was because the `post_exists( $slug , '', '', 'page')` returned a truthy value.

For example just to test it, for

```php
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
echo post_exists( 'home', '', '', 'page');
```

it echoed `363`, so I went to the database to check and found that not only is it not deleted per se, but it appears as published:

```sql
mysql> SELECT ID, post_name, post_title, post_status, post_type FROM wordpress.wp_posts WHERE ID=3
63;
+-----+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| ID  | post_name | post_title | post_status | post_type |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 363 | home      | Home       | published   | page      |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know I'm probably overlooking a fundamental and basic thing about how wordpress works, but I didn't find anything useful while searching for this.

So, how can I delete posts definitively without actually going to the database and deleting it?

Comment: The record should not be in the database after you emptied the trash. Either you're somehow looking at different posts, or you have a hook in your theme or a plugin that is interfering with standard WP behaviour.

Comment: I'm not looking at different posts, because I specifically looked them up by id in the database. I could have a hook that interferes, but I have no idea what could it be, as I didn't really do anything out of the ordinary that I can think of. The other thing is, that programatically added posts don't show up at all on the admin page.

Comment: Did you deleted or sent them to trash _manually_ from admin panel,  or _programmatically_, using your own functions? The second is more convenient, because it sounds like. So, show us your secret code.

Comment: No, I deleted them on the admin panel. I wanted to add them programatically and this didn't work at first because the condition in this returned false, meaning the post_exist evaluated to truthy and that's how I found that the posts still exist.

`if ( ! post_exists( $slug, '', '', 'page') ) {
    $postarr = array(
        'post_name' => $slug,
        ...
    );
    wp_insert_post( $postarr );
}`

Comment: After stashing all changes is still get the following warnings when trying to visit the deleted pages:
Notice: Trying to get property 'public' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 242 
Notice: Trying to get property 'protected' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 242
Notice: Trying to get property 'private' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 243
Notice: Trying to get property 'exclude_from_search' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 243

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.